# How do I map emojis to numerical values in my Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I need a functionality in my angular 6 app to implement that different emojis have different numerical values.

For example, if a post is created by a user which has 3 sad and 2 smiley emojis then the resulting values will be `2 x 3 = 6`  and `4 x 2 = 8`.

How do I map these emojis to numerical values so that I can perform calculations on these values?

Comment: posting some of your code would help

Comment: @Roxy'Pro While I agree, generally, that posting existing code is a good idea, in this case it's perfectly clear what the OP needs help understanding, and it's likewise clear that the existing code doesn't actually matter much to the question.  Sometimes I think folks are too quick with the Close button on here, with new folks who aren't certain what approach to take on a given problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an object in JS that translates between the emoji code and value like:

```
    const emojiValues = { “&#x1F354”: 1 }
    let value = emojiValues[“&#x1F354”] // fetch if back
```

More detailed discussion on how to use emojis in HTML is here: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/emoji.htm